# Custom Object in ArrayList and Searchable

Tags: java, object, arraylist, jfilechooser

I have created a custom object called FileType

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

class FileType
{
    private int     index;
    private String  type;
    private String  extension;
    private String  description;
    ImageIcon       icon;

    public FileType(int index, String type, String extension, String description, String icon)
    {
        this.index = index;
        this.type = type;
        this.extension = extension;
        this.description = description;
        this.icon = Utils.createImageIcon(icon);
    }

    public int getIndex()
    {
        return index;
    }

    public String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public String getExtension()
    {
        return extension;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public ImageIcon getIcon()
    {
        return icon;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I also created a FileList class

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FileList extends AbstractList
{

    private ArrayList<FileType> fileList;

    public FileList()
    {
    }

    public void add(int index, String type, String extension, String description, String icon)
    {
        FileType data = new FileType(index, type, extension, description, icon);
        if (!fileList.contains(data))
        {
            fileList.add(data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(int index)
    {
        return fileList.toArray()[index];
    }

    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        return fileList.size();
    }
}
```

Now i want to create objects such as

- "1","html","ASCII HTML Files","images/html.png"
- "2","html","Bootstrap HTML Files","images/html.png"

Now I am lost because i want to say say something like:

list.findelementbytype ("html"); which would return FileType object, which i could then access and fetch the remaining values/attributes.

Am i on the right track or am i doing this wrong? This is for a File Chooser i am writing and i wanted to have all of the relevant data in a single object. More OO, thank you!

---

**SOLUTION**

The File Type Class which creates each data entry.

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

class FileType
{
    private int     index;
    private String  search;
    private String  type;
    private String  extension;
    private String  description;
    ImageIcon       icon;

    public FileType(int index, String search, String type, String extension, String description, String icon)
    {
        this.index = index;
        this.search = search;
        this.type = type;
        this.extension = extension;
        this.description = description;
        this.icon = Utils.createImageIcon(icon);
    }

    public int getIndex()
    {
        return index;
    }

    public String getSearch()
    {
        return search;
    }

    public String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    public String getExtension()
    {
        return extension;
    }

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }

    public ImageIcon getIcon()
    {
        return icon;
    }
}
```

The Custom ArrayList Object which maintains the data.

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class FileList extends AbstractList
{
    private ArrayList<FileType> fileList;

    public FileList()
    {
        fileList = new ArrayList<FileType>();
    }

    public void add(String search, String type, String extension, String description, String icon)
    {

        FileType data = new FileType(fileList.size(), search, type, extension, description, icon);
        if (!fileList.contains(data))
        {
        fileList.add(data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(int index)
    {
        return fileList.toArray()[index];
    }

    public int getIndex(String search)
    {
        for (FileType obj : fileList)
        {
            if ((obj.getSearch()).equalsIgnoreCase(search))
                return obj.getIndex();
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public String getType(String search)
    {
        for (FileType obj : fileList)
        {
            if ((obj.getSearch()).equalsIgnoreCase(search))
                return obj.getType();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public String getExtension(int index)
    {
        for (FileType obj : fileList)
        {
            if (obj.getIndex() == index)
                return obj.getExtension();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public String getExtension(String search)
    {
        for (FileType obj : fileList)
        {
            if ((obj.getSearch()).equalsIgnoreCase(search))
                return obj.getExtension();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public String getDescription(String search)
    {
        for (FileType obj : fileList)
        {
            if ((obj.getSearch()).equalsIgnoreCase(search))
                return obj.getDescription();
        }
        return "";
    }

    public ImageIcon getIcon(String search)
    {
        for (FileType obj : fileList)
        {
            if ((obj.getSearch()).equalsIgnoreCase(search))
                return obj.getIcon();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size()
    {
        return fileList.size();
    }
}
```

And you would call this by:

```
    FileList list = new FileList();
    list.add("html", "random desc html", Utils.html, "ASCII HTML Files", "images/html.png");
    list.add("bootstrap.html", "random desc bootstrap", Utils.bootstrap, "Bootstrap HTML Files",
            "images/bootstrap.png");
    list.add("xml", "random desc xml", Utils.xml, "XML Files", "images/xml.png");
    list.add("json", "random desc json", Utils.json, "JSON Files", "images/json.png");
    list.add("pdf", "random desc pdf", Utils.pdf, "PDF Documents", "images/pdf.png");
    list.add("doc", "random desc doc", Utils.doc, "Google Documents", "images/doc.png");
```

These classes were created to augment JFilechooser into a more OO manner when adding custom filters, view conditions and icons.

I am sure this is not optimal when it comes to performance and a hash map would be a more ideal choice but for my purposes and time constraints this does the job i want :)

Comment: If they are only going to search by file extension, then you can put all of your FileType objects into a HashMap, where the key is the "html", "xml", etc. That would make retrieval easy. If however, you expect to be able to search by id or extesion, or another field, you will have to use another way, maybe another Class to encapsulate the searchable behavior.

Comment: I Also create the FileList Class but i am getting a null pointer exception in the add method :(

Comment: You never initialize fileList. Change your line at the top to: `ArrayList<FileType> fileList = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: I realized that myself, thank you! :)

Comment: 2 more comments: 1) If you were to extend AbstractList, I don't think you need to keep a local ArrayList to store the FileTypes, in your add, just call super.add(fileType). Secondly if you are going to call `.contains`, you need to have a `Comparator` that can compare your custom FileType object.

Comment: Can you add an explanation of how you would search for the correct fileType? Would it always be by the extension: "html" ?

Comment: I am defining a FileType object saying that it has 6 parameters which are: index, search, type, extension, description, icon. What do you mean search for the correct file type? Iterate through the FileList and find the other associated values by 'search' or 'index'. So for example when you are setting for a JFileChooser what you consider to be accepted input. You iterate through the list and add values that are in the FileList array! Did that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `HashMap` where you map the desired property to the object. If you want to get your objects using more than one property, you can create multiple `HashMap`. The problem of this approach is that you end up with one map for each property you want to look after and you can only get object per key.

If you're looking for sorting, my suggestion is to use a `TreeMap` and fiddle around with the `Comparator`interface, which allows to implement comparators for multiple properties.

**Edit:**
Since there may be too many properties to look after and the goal is not sorting, maybe the best way is to keep using `ArrayList` with the addition of `Checker` classes, which check if a `File` has a specified property value.
It works like the `Comparator` interface (the generics here are optional):

```
public interface Checker<T>
{
    public boolean hasProperty(T o);
}
```

An example of a `Checker` class to find a `File` by its name:

```
public class FileNameChecker implements Checker<File>
{
    private String name;

    public FileNameChecker(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasProperty(File f) {
        return f.getName().equals(name);
    }

}
```

And in your file system, the generic `find` method:

```
public File find(Checker<File> checker) {
    for(File f : fileList) {
        if(checker.hasProperty(f))
            return f;
    }
    return null;
}
```

And call it with:

```
find(new FileNameChecker("Filename"))
```

Note that you can easily modify `find` to return more than one `File`.

If you chose to follow this solution, I suggest you take a look at Java 8 lambdas and `Stream` methods, namely `filter`. These basically ease all this process.

Comment: I'm not very experienced with any of those, is there any way to do with ArrayList or do you have an example you can suggest? I Also create the FileList Class but i am getting a null pointer exception in the add method :(

Comment: @codeCompiler77 I updated my answer with a better solution, using only `ArrayList`.

Comment: It's kind of what i did myself, i posted my solution in my original question. If you have any tips about my solution above, let me know. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get a list of all FileTypes in fileList that match a given type then this should do the trick:

```
public ArrayList<FileType> findElementByType(String type){
  ArrayList<FileType> matchingFiles = new ArrayList<FileType>();
  for (FileType file : fileList){
    if (file.getType.equals(type)){
      matchingFiles.add(file); 
    }
  }
  return matchingFiles;
}
```

Correct me if I misunderstood you

Comment: Nope, you're pretty much right, i did a hybrid of your solution and Bifz below. Thanks for the help! I posted my working code in the question above. If you have any tips let me know :)