# Java JFileChooser append extension on filter change

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have filters

- All
- html
- txt

Depending on which filter is selected, append the extension to the JFileChooser or disallow the user to enter an extension.

Not after they press save button but while the window is open.

I was looking at addPropertyChangeListener but i can't find anything outside of the file change property.

EDIT: I got this far, i can get the filter to be added but i still have no idea how to fetch the associated filter.

```
            fc.addPropertyChangeListener(JFileChooser.FILE_FILTER_CHANGED_PROPERTY, new PropertyChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt)
                {
                    **MyFileFilter** filter = (**MyFileFilter**) evt.getNewValue();
                    String extension = filter.getExtensionByDescription(filter.getDescription());
                    //String extension = "ext"; // somehow here
                    fc.setSelectedFile(new File("." + extension));
                }
            });
```

---

**SOLUTION**

Create a custom class that extends FilerFilter

```
    public String getExtensionByDescription(String description)
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < fileList.size(); i++)          
        {
            if (description.contains(fileList.get(i).getDescription()))
            {
                return "." + fileList.get(i).getExtension();
            }
        }
//      for (FileType obj : fileList)
//      {
//          if (description.contains(obj.getDescription()))
//              return "." +  obj.getExtension();
//      }
        return "";
    }
```

On a side question, does anyone know why the commented out for loop doesn't work? It returns the wrong Extension but it is logically the same thing as the above loop :S

Comment: `JFileChooser` seems to raise the `fileFilterChanged` property changed event for me

Comment: I saw that, but the only method available is getDescription which for me doesn't contain the extension :(

Comment: The ask the `JFileChooser` for the current filter when the event is triggered

Comment: @MadProgrammer I figured it out. Creating a custom class that extends FilterFilter. With a method getExtension that uses the description to fetch the extension. I'll post the post once I'm done. Thanks!

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added my working solutions, one quick question. Any idea why the commented out for loop doesn't work? I look at them and they are functionally the same but the commented out for loop, returns the wrong value :(

Comment: You know, since you're casting the `FileFilter`, why not simply supply a method in your filter to get the extension directly?

Comment: There are three classes at play here. FileType which is a custom class that defines 6 parameters: index, search, type, extension, description, icon.  Next we have FileList which extends AbstractArray list, both of them can be found here [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677855/custom-object-in-arraylist-and-searchable). Finally we have MyFileFilter which extends FileFilter and has two methods boolean accept and String getDescription and now has getExtensionByDescription. I iterate through the array list to find the associated extension if it exists. Did that answer your question?